# Customizer: Category Select Sanitize

Tags: php, theme-customizer, sanitization, callbacks

as a noob I managed out to create a custom selectbox control for categories in customizer.
But now I am trying to find a clever 'sanitize_callback' function in order to ensure security. Here is my approach so far:

```
function bloook_sanitize_category_select( $cat_id, $setting) {
    $cat_id = absint($cat_id);
    return is_string(get_the_category_by_ID( $cat_id )) ? $cat_id :  $setting->default;
}
```

But I am not convinced that this is a satisfactory. 
The functionality is still fine, but how do I test the security?

So I wonder if someone is out there who can help. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: what you are not sure?

Comment: WordPress offers a lot of sanitization/escape functions. Check here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation

Comment: looks all good.

Comment: @TurbinE: Thank you and sorry for my English. I am not sure if my code is secure, because I don't know how to test the security.  My PHP skills are not very sophisticated. I found a lot of tutorials for making a category field in customizer I did not find one with a 'sanitize_callback' for it. So I made my own as shown above in the hope that if its lousy or riskiy someone might give me a hint... .

Comment: @majick: Thanks to your comment I am feeling better with it. Thank you.